# Why is php throwing timeout reading a small file?

Tags: php, timeout, fread

It does not run out of memory, but it throws the 30 seconds timeout, and if i raise the timeout value, it still throw the timeout exception.
Here's the code that open and read the file:

```
$path = ROOT_PATH . '/library/Pixel/views/teste.tpl';
@file_get_contents($path);
```

So, what may be the problem?

Comment: try to remove the @ to see what error is happening

Comment: echo $path and check it wheather the path is correct or not?

Comment: First of all remove the `@` this makes it harder to debug. Once you remove the `@` You will probley get a error. Before you use file_get_contents you can also check if the file exists and if so, than do file contents